# Undefined index, and undefined variable, but both are defined! (I think....)

Tags: php, html, oop, pdo

I am using the HTML form below to pass a file to PHP for handling.  But PHP says that the index is undefined.

Also, similarly, a variable I defined in config.php is showing as undefined.

What am I missing here?

**classes.php**

```
<?php
require('config.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
 * Classes required by the script
 * 
 */

class database extends PDO
{
    public $conURL;

    public function __construct($config) {
        $conURL = "mysql:host=" . $config['host'] . ";dbname=" . $config['db'];
        try {
         parent::__construct($conURL, $config['user'], $config['pass']);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }       
}

class upload
{
    public $_FILES;

    public function uploadFile() {
        if ($_FILES['file']['size'] >= 2000000) {
           echo "File is too large!";
        }
        elseif (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
           $stmt = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
           $stmt->execute(array($_FILES['file']['name'], $_FILES['file']['type'], $_FILES['file']['size'], $_FILES['file']['file']));
        }
    }
}
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$config = array(
        'host' => 'localhost', // db host
        'user' => 'root', // db user
        'pass' => 'mypassword', //db pass
        'db' => 'files' // db name
);
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require('config.php');
require('classes.php');

$dbh = new database($config);
$upload = new upload();
$upload->uploadFile();
```

**HTML form**

```
<form name="uploaddb" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
<input type="file" name="file" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

And for reference, here are the errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: config in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/classes.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/classes.php on line 34

Comment: Storing files in database is not a good practise. store a url to the file in Database and save the file to hard disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it, but here is what I think is wrong:

1. Do not require `config.php` on the class files. You are already passing `$config` to the `database` constructor.
2. Do not declare `$_FILES` on your classes, it's a superglobal available everywhere.

I'd also recommend you capitalize your class names.

**UPDATE**

Sorry that I can't put it all together right now. Here is a couple more problems I see:

1. There's no `file` key on `$_FILES['file']`. Not sure which key you're looking for.
2. You can't use db methods on class `upload` as it is now. Isn't `$this->prepare` causing an error? That class does not extend `PDO`. Maybe you should have the upload method inside the db class.

Comment: I'll capitalize them now.  Thanks.  

The remaining error is something to do with this part:  $_FILES['file']['file']. I am confused as to what variable I should replace that with in order to insert the uploaded file to the database.

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out, if I replace $_FILES['file']['file'] with just $_FILES['file'], the data is inserted into the database, but I get a notice about an array to string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I dearly hope you are not actually processing this: `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />`

Also, use `global $config;`

Comment: LOL.  I am not, you can see all of the code above.  And I was told that globalizing variables is bad.

Comment: If a variable is out of scope, sometimes you must. However, since you are only using it in a class file, it should be fine without apparent conflict.

Comment: Where did you place it? Inside or outside of the class ?

Comment: I placed it in config.php, where the variable itself is defined.

Comment: @Dustin: It would need to be in `__construct` of the `database` class to do anything helpful.

Comment: I put it in the uploadFile() method and that seems to have fixed that error.  Thanks to both of you! :) Although one error still remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct() {
    global $config;
    // Rest of the code here.
}
```

Not exactly a great way to do it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are including config.php again in classes.php file

the second thing is  last argument of execute ,file content is stored in
there is no file index in $_FILES

```
 $_FILE['file']['tmp_name']


 $stmt->execute(array($_FILES['file']['name']
 , $_FILES['file']['type'], $_FILES['file']['size'], $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

Do not store files in Database its and overkill.